# Want to render different component after click on Add Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, semantic-ui

I want to render VehicleInfoRender.js when click on 'Add' button which is in UMUIMAdditionalCoverage.js

App.js

```
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BasicLayout />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a state to manage toggling `VehicleInfoRender`

```
state = { activeIndex: 0,  showVehicleInfo: false}
```

Then add a function to toggle showing and hiding the component

```
<Button onClick={this.toggleVehicleInfo}>Add</Button>

const toggleVehicleInfo = () => {
 this.setState((prevState) => {showVehicleInfo: !prevState.showVehicleInfo});
};
```

Finally add this where you want to render the component

```
{this.state.showVehicleInfo && <VehicleInfoRender />}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use state (eg: `isShowVehicleInfoRender`) to handle turn on/off render this component